# phalcon treat bit fields as string

Tags: data-binding, model, bit, phalcon

I have a problem for setting bit fields in my tables.
when I want to set a bit field like confirmed=0 because phalcon bind it as string ('0') the final result will be confirmed=1.
I can change all of my bit fields type to tinyint(1) but it will takes too much time for me because I have so many bit fields in many tables.

in phalcon documentation there is an example for specifying binding type as below:

```
<?php

use \Phalcon\Db\Column;

//Bind parameters
$parameters = array(
    "name" => "Robotina",
    "year" => 2008
);

//Casting Types
$types = array(
    "name" => Column::BIND_PARAM_STR,
    "year" => Column::BIND_PARAM_INT
);

// Query robots binding parameters with string placeholders
$robots = Robots::find(array(
    "name = :name: AND year = :year:",
    "bind" => $parameters,
    "bindTypes" => $types
));
```

but this is for retrieving data. I want to know is it possible to do same thing for storing data with save method? for example do something in beforeSave() method like checking metaData for bit type and bind these data as Int value!

I also tried to use 'b0' instead of 0 but that didn’t worked!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps its in the metadata structure of the model

Annotations are the easiest way to set that:
http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#annotations-strategy

```
class Model extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{

    /**
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    public $bitColumn;
}
```

Alternatively you can use beforeValidationOnSave and afterFetch to transform the values

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already checked for annotation but it didn't worked.first I used @var integer annotation and after your answer I changed it to @Column(type="integer") but the result was same. may be the only way is using beforeValidation and if that doesn't work too, changing columns type in database table